# Is it possible to write a complete research paper in R?

Tags: r

I know that using knitr one can generate reports, etc but is it possible to write a complete paper in R? That is, including all diagrams, citation of referred works, heading styles, etc like you do in Microsoft Word. I am asking about non R research i.e. analyses done in R (for example Road Traffic Engineering analyses) but not related to R or programming.

Comment: (1) Of course it's possible; reports aren't *that* different than papers, are they? (2) For some examples, see the "Books" and the "Papers and reports" sections of [http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/showcase/](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/showcase/)

Comment: if you mean LaTeX+bibtex+R+knitr, yes.  You can write a [whole book](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/) that way, and lots of people do (I think I might have done one or two diagrams in xfig, but you can do that).

Comment: My experience, for what it is worth, is that you can do it, but you probably wouldn't want to. There are many nice features that word processors offer that you probably would not want to give up.  But, yes it is possible.

Comment: can you please clarify whether "in R" means "in R markdown" or "in (possibly knitr-flavoured) Sweave" ? (or something else, but I have a hard time imagining other possibilities ?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about presentation tools rather than about programming (also somewhat unclear ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think citations and header styles seem like a problem.
You might want to have a look at [brew package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html), which in my opinion is better for mixing output with R [(presentation)](http://www.slideshare.net/xavierguardiola/building-a-reporting-sytem-with-brew). I think there are mostly tools to render R objects into specific formatting like ([Pander](http://rapporter.github.io/), [xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html), [stargazer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/index.html), etc).